# Why $T(z)=az+b$ is called a Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, transformation

As we always read in Complex Analysis, Linear Transformation (L.T.) is a combination of Translation, Rotation and Magnification i.e. $T(z)=az+b$ is a L.T. in complex. However, it doesn't satisfy the linearity properties

(1) $T(z_1+z_2)=T(z_1)+T(z_2)$

(2) $T(az)=aT(z)$.

So, my question is that if $T(z)=az+b$ doesn't satisfy the properties of L.T. then why it is called a L.T.?

Please make it clear to me. It's very urgent.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasonable definitions of "linear", if you imagine that you're the first mathematician to define this term.

1. A transformation that sends lines to lines. A good example is "translation". Lines form natural subsets of euclidean spaces, esp. if you've studied geometry a la Euclid, so preserving this structure leads to interesting characteristics for a transformation; it needs a name, so you pick "linear." One might call this the "geometric" definition.
2. A transformation that sends subspaces of a vector space to subspaces. In a vector space, which is a sort of natural generalization of the real numbers in which you have scalar multiplication instead of multiplication, not all lines are the same: the ones through the origin have special properties (closed under addition and scalar multiplication). So *they* tend to be the ones that you study a lot. And transformations that preserve these important lines get called "linear." One might call this the "algebraic" definition.

The first usage is the one informally used in complex vars; the second is the one used in linear algebra.(*)

There's a unification, however. If you imagine the $z = 1$ plane of $xyz$-space, you can look at the special class of linear (in the second sense) transformations of $xyz$-space that send the $z = 1$ plane to itself. These turn out to be exactly the linear (in the first sense) transformations of the $z = 1$ plane.

You can even generalize a bit: look at any transformation $T$ of $xyz$-space, and follow it by the map 
$$
H: \mathbb R^3 - \{ (x, y, 0) | x, y \in \mathbb R \} \to \mathbb R^3: (x, y, z) \mapsto (x/z, y/z, 1),
$$
which folks in computer graphics call "homogenization" (which is exactly the wrong word). The transformation $H \circ T$ will send the $z = 1$ plane to itself, with just a tiny problem: If $T(a, b, 1) = (p, q, 0)$, then $H \circ T$ won't be defined for the point $(a, b, 1)$. Or you might say that because you divided by zero, the result is a "point at infinity." That sounds like nonsense, but is in fact the starting point of projective geometry; for a lovely introduction, once you know a little abstract algebra, see Hartshorne's book "Foundations of Projective Geometry."

(*) It's not enough to say "sends line-subspaces to line-subspaces". Consider the map on the plane that defines $T(x, y) = (x, y)$ if $x/y$ is rational, and $(0,0)$ otherwise. That satisfies $T(\alpha \mathbf u) = \alpha T(\mathbf u)$, but not the addition rule (although it satisfies the addition rule on each line-subspace of the plane!). But it's certainly not linear!

Answer (score 0):

The proper name should be *linear fractional transformation*, not just "linear transformation", but some textbooks are a little sloppy.

As you point out, they are **not** linear in the usual sense of the words. However, they are [projective transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_transformation) and in fact form the so called [projective linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group) of $\mathbb{C}$, which also happens to be the automorphism group of the Riemann sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Actually the linear fractional transformations are different from linear transformations and linear fractional transformations are defined as $$T(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ which is a generalization of linear transformation.
So the conclusion is that we should not say that $T(z)=az+b$ is a linear transformation.